# How to install Reactstrap with React-Starter-kit

Tags: react-starter-kit, reactstrap

react-starter-kit
https://github.com/kriasoft/react-starter-kit

reactstrap
http://reactstrap.github.io/

What are the steps to install the reactstrap into the react-starter-kit? in order to use the grid layout?

http://reactstrap.github.io/components/layout/

Comment: Do you need css to be packed by webpack? It's much simpler just to use the standard css from a cdn. installing / using the components is trivial.

Answer (score 1):

Steps:

1. Download the repo
2. Type in the terminal:

```sh
yarn add reactstrap
yarn add react-transition-group
yarn add bootstrap
```

3. In your component files, type the following code:

```js
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
import { Container, Row, Col } from 'reactstrap';
```

4. Then you can test reactstrap's Layout feature in your render function like so:

```html
<Container>
  <Row>
    <Col>.col</Col>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <Col>.col</Col>
    <Col>.col</Col>
    <Col>.col</Col>
    <Col>.col</Col>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <Col xs="3">.col-3</Col>
    <Col xs="auto">.col-auto - variable width content</Col>
    <Col xs="3">.col-3</Col>
  </Row>
</Container>
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using [create-react-app](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app)? That's what I am using...

```sh
npm install -g create-react-app
create-react-app my-app
```

Then, follow the instructions on reactstrap's [README](https://github.com/reactstrap/reactstrap) to install bootstrap, reactstrap, react and react-dom:

```sh
npm install --save reactstrap@next react-addons-transition-group
react-addons-css-transition-group bootstrap@4.0.0-beta.2
react-dom@^16.0.0
```

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using `npm` rather than `yarn`:

```sh
npm i --save reactstrap # (http://reactstrap.github.io/)
npm i --save react-bootstrap bootstrap # (https://react-bootstrap.github.io/)
npm install --save reactstrap react react-dom # (http://reactstrap.github.io/);
```

But I think that the last one is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can install reactstrap using npm / yarn package manager.

**Installation**

```
npm install reactstrap react react-dom
```

Import Bootstrap in your application code:

```
npm install --save bootstrap
```

or

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
```

**Usage**

```
import React from 'react';
import { Button } from 'reactstrap';

export default (props) => {
  return (
    <Button color="danger">Danger!</Button>
  );
};
```

For more:
[Reactstrap - installation](https://reactstrap.github.io/?path=/story/home-installation--page)