# Getting Error "React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string" when using React Router and external component that imports other Components

Tags: reactjs, react-router, reactstrap

I'm getting the following error when trying to use a component such as the {Input} from 'reactstrap' in an external component, it seems I'm not importing the reactstrap well with the rest of my component somehow.

My **App.jsx** goes like this:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Login from './Login';
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Link, Route} from 'react-router-dom'

class App extends Component {
render() {
    return (
        <Router>
            <div className="App">
                <Link to="/login">
                    <h3 className="App-menu-title">Login</h3>
                </Link>
                <Route exact={true} path="/" component={Login}/>
            </div>
        </Router>)
}
}

export default App;
```

And here's my **Login.jsx**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
 import {Input} from 'bootstrap';


class Login extends Component {
render() {
    return (
        <div>
        <Input />
        </div>
    )
}
}

export default Login;
```

and here's the error I get

```
index.js:2178 Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- 
expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for 
composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export 
your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed 
up default and named imports.

Check your code at Login.jsx:9.
in Login (created by Route)
in Route (at App.jsx:14)
in div (at App.jsx:10)
in Router (created by BrowserRouter)
in BrowserRouter (at App.jsx:9)
in App (at index.js:9)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are importing the `Input` component wrongly, you need to import it from `reactstrap` and you are instead importing it from `bootstrap`

```
import {Input} from 'reactstrap';
```

Comment: Thanks! That fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

You import from bootstrap, not from reactstrap...

If you are using [create-react-app](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app) and have problems using reactstrap, the following may help: [How to install Reactstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48384160/5532513).

For a example of a form with controlled components, using reactstrap, you may look [here](https://github.com/rahamin1/reactstrap-form).

Answer (score 0):

You need to import Input from `reactstrap` instead of `bootstrap`

```
import { Input } from 'reactstrap'
```